# Retrieve javascript object on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Example**

Suppose I have an array of school objects in javascript...

```
schools =

[
    {name: "School A", phone: "Phone A", location: "Location A"},
    {name: "School B", phone: "Phone B", location: "Location B"},
    {name: "School C", phone: "Phone C", location: "Location C"},
    ...
]
```

... and I want to display the schools names in paragraph tags ...

```
<p data-name="School A">School A</p>
<p data-name="School B">School B</p>
<p data-name="School C">School C</p>
```

... when I click on a given school paragraph, I want to display the additional info in a separate pane.  For example, when I click on School A...

```
<div id="separate-pane">
    <p>Phone A</p>
    <p>Address A</p>
</div>
```

To do this, I need to retrieve the associated object, create the additional info paragraph tags, and append them to the separate pane. How do I go about referencing the correct javascript object when clicking on a given school name paragraph in an efficient way?

**Thoughts/Ideas**

1. Use innerHTML

   - On click paragraph, extract the school name from innerHTML
   - Iterate through javascript array and when obj.name == innerHTML, we have found a match
2. Use data-name attribute

   - Same as above, but obj.name == data-name

Both of these ways should work, but is there a better way to do this without having to iterate through the javascript array to find the correct object?
Also, what is this process called that I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: why not "writing" all the HTML as it should be and just hide / show the panned content upon clicking on it?

Comment: what if attached to each school is an array of images that should also be displayed?  And there are thousands of schools.  Won't it over populate the DOM?

Comment: @MikeB - you have had a number of suggestions and answrs, and you are adding clarifications within different comment section. Can I politely suggest, given you have more information to hand with which you are able to clarify, that you update your original post to specify exactly what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Nicolas's answer, when you're creating the HTML from the `schools` array, you can put the array index into a data attribute:

```
$.each(schools, function(i, school) {
    $("#links").append($("<p>", {
        "class": "link",
        text: school.name,
        data: { index: i }
    });
});

$(".link").click(function() {
    var school = schools[$(this).data("index");
    // display school information in #separate-pane
});
```

Comment: I upvoted this as a good answer, although technically, you are changing the array to be an object, which isn't quite what the OP, Mike B, asked. Technically, Nicolas answer keeps the array of objects as-is, so he gets an upvote too ;-)

Comment: Not just technically, I'm deliberately recommending that he change his design.

Comment: I would too if I controlled where the array object is sourced from. But that isn't specified in the question, so who knows where the array is coming from - e.g. it might be populated as the result of an AJAX call, or sourced from some 3rd-party library or dataset, etc.

Comment: It's trivial to write a loop that converts the input array into my object.

Comment: @Kit I've added the trivial loop to my answer.

Comment: This only works if the names are unique correct? I couldn't have say "Sunnyside Elementary" twice with different locations.

Comment: Agreed - and if the array is externally sourced, then that is what I would do - assuming the expected array length is long. Otherwise, if there are only a few schools, then probably as easy and efficient to iterate the array at 'click' time, rather than at page initialisation time.

Comment: @MikeB If you have duplicate names, how will any code know which one is intended from `data-name="Sunnyside Elementary"`? You need some kind of unique identifier.

Comment: Is it possible to create an onclick event handler when creating the school name paragraphs when you have access to the current school object?  and in that event handler you empty the seperate pane, create the additonal paragraphs, and append them?

Comment: Are you creating the paragraphs dynamically from the `schools` array? In that case, I suggest going with @Nicolas's answer, you can put the array index in a data attribute.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this as the answer.  I actually do prefer your original idea of creating a dictionary between school name and the additional info.  However, I wasn't sure if I could leave the original data structure in question, as it might have caused a heated debate :)

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the index in a data parameter in the HTML, and then use the index to find the associate school in your school array. Simple code :

```
<p data-name="School A" data-index="0">School A</p>
<p data-name="School B" data-index="1">School B</p>
<p data-name="School C" data-index="2">School C</p>



$(document).ready(function(){
    var school =  [
        {name: "School A", phone: "Phone A", location: "Location A"},
        {name: "School B", phone: "Phone B", location: "Location B"},
        {name: "School C", phone: "Phone C", location: "Location C"},
        ...
    ]
    $('.button').on('click', function(){
        var index = $(this).data('index');
        var data = school[index];
        //Use the data to show the info.
    });
})
```

Comment: Good answer so I upvoted, although, if Mike B's adding data attribs anyway (for your index) then he might as well get rid of the array altogether,  add 'data-phone' and 'data-location' to each paragraph element, and feed them through to his target div!

Comment: That would work as well but if he want's to add another field, let say adresse, he will need to add it directly into the HTML, the upside to have a index is that it does not alter HTML, only the array in the background. Making the code way more scalable.

Comment: Agreed Nicolas. This question is a little lacking in it's objectives for an answer, so there could be lots of solutions with a subjective bias towards any individual answer, any one of which could be 'better' than any other, based on a wider context of the true problem at hand and what the OP is really looking for.

Comment: That's a really good point you got there. i guess both our solutions are ok in the current context. Anyways, I hope we helped the OP to get where he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If using jquery on click listener you can use $(this).data("name") to get data stored in data-name attriburw

Answer (score 0):

You can store whole school object in the created `p` element using jQuery `data` functionality and then retrieve it on element click, like below.  Check demo - [Fiddle Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/5k0jn8uy/)

```
var schools = [
    {name: "School A", phone: "Phone A", location: "Location A"},
    {name: "School B", phone: "Phone B", location: "Location B"},
    {name: "School C", phone: "Phone C", location: "Location C"}
]

schools.forEach(function(item){
  var $el = $('<p>' + item.name + '</p>');
  $.data($el[0], item); // store school object with the element
  $el.click(function(){
        $('#separate-pane').html( $.data(this, item).phone + ' '+ $.data(this, item).location ); // retrieve saved school object
  })  
    $('#schools').append($el);
})
```